# Filter elements containing search term anywhere

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently I have a function that filters my list based on the input, however it tries to match with the first letter only rather than looking for the input text anywhere. For example, what I mean is when a user types "Eng" it will match with "England" and remove the others this is fine, however if a user types "land" this comes up with no matches rather than showing all countries in the list that have "land" in their name.

```
$(function() {
    $("input").keyup(function() {
        var val = $(this).val();
        $("ul li").show().filter(function() {
            return $(this).text().toLowerCase().trim().indexOf(val);
        }).hide();
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w7hb44w0/) to show what I currently use:

Comment: Just add [`=== -1`](https://jsfiddle.net/w7hb44w0/1/) in `filter()` condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
$(function () {
  $("input").keyup(function () {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $("ul li").show().filter(function () {
        if($(this).text().toLowerCase().trim().indexOf(val) > -1){
           return 0;
        }
        return 1;
    }).hide();
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zwLsackq/1/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using then take advantage of `:contains`. This method will return jQuery object containing all the matched elements.

```js
$(function() {
  $("input").keyup(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $("ul > li").hide();
    $("ul > li:contains('" + val + "')").show();
  });
});
```

```css
input {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

ul {
  margin: 10px 0 0;
}

li {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="inp" />
<ul>
  <li>England</li>
  <li>Wales</li>
  <li>Scotland</li>
  <li>Ireland</li>
</ul>
```